# android webview showing blank page returning from other activity

Tags: android, webview

I have set orientation MainWebActivity to PORTRAIT and GameActivityLandscape  to LANDSCAPE in AndroidManifest.xml when i start activity GameActivityLandscape in shouldOverrideUrlLoading ,but when i press back button from GameActivityLandscape  then there appears a blank page,I want MainWebActivity as like first time load

My MainWebActivity is

```
public class MainWebActivity extends Activity {
private WebView myWebView;
ProgressBar progressBar;
boolean internet;
Bundle webState=null;
String GMTag="MainWebActivity ";
static String lodUrl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(webview);

    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    //myWebView.clearCache(true);
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Log.d(GMTag, " onResume webview load ");
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://html5games.com/Game/Civilizations-Wars-Master-Edition/2001681a-0f53-4691-9318-04e419ac7c0c");
    }

}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(GMTag, "Main Web shouldOverrideUrlLoading test" + url.toString());
        return handleUri(url);
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        Log.d(GMTag, "Main Web android N shouldOverrideUrlLoading " + request.getUrl().toString());
        //final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
        return handleUri(request.getUrl().toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    /*public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
        //Your code to do
        Toast.makeText(MainWebActivity.this, "Your Internet Connection May not be active Or " + error.getDescription() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }*/
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        if(errorCode==404){
            Toast.makeText(MainWebActivity.this, "File or directry not found" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainWebActivity.this, "Your Internet Connection May not be active Or " + description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
}
private boolean handleUri(String url) {

   if (url.contains("fg_domain=play.famobi.com&fg_aid=A1000-1&fg_uid=2001681a-0f53-4691-9318-04e419ac7c0c&fg_pid=4638e320-4444-4514-81c4-d80a8c662371&"))
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainWebActivity.this, GameActivityLandscape.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("URL", url); //Optional parameters
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        MainWebActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myWebView.onPause();
    Log.d(GMTag, " Web onPause called " + webState);
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@JavascriptInterface
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myWebView.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.d(GMTag, " onSaveInstanceState ");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    webState=outState;
    myWebView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(GMTag, " webview restored in onRestoreInstanceState ");
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    myWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    myWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

This is my GameActivityLandscape activity

```
public class GameActivityLandscape extends Activity {
private WebView myWebView;
static String gameRotation, gameUrl;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    gameRotation = intent.getStringExtra("ORIENTATION");
    gameUrl = intent.getStringExtra("URL");

    //progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.game_progressBar);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.game_webview);

    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        myWebView.loadUrl(gameUrl);
    }
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

        Log.d("Game", "onError landscape called " + failingUrl);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myWebView.onResume();
    Log.d("Game", "onresume called of gameacticity landcape ");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("Game", "onPause called of gameacticity landcape ");
    myWebView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.i("Gaming mania", "Play game landscape activity finish");
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Comment: Write this line in your manifest file where your activity is declared android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize".

Comment: @AndyDeveloper no, it's not working, i also used android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in manifest